# how to modify clone of an html table?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make some sort of survey form. I managed to increase id and name dynamically and i can add different answer types. The problem is when i want to add radiobutton it adds 5 of them. same as checkbox too. But when try to add textfield, i want it to add only 1 but it adds 5 because of my hidden table's structure.

hoca can i solve this problem? here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>clone table - 2.0</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    });
    function cloneRadio() {
        var aydi = $('input#gizli').val();
        $table = $('table#table0').clone().attr('id', 'table' + aydi).attr(
                'name', 'table' + aydi).appendTo("#div1");
        $("input[type='radio']", $table).prop("name", "ans" + aydi);
        $("p", $table).prop("id", "questionTXT_" + aydi);
        aydi++;
        $('input#gizli').val(aydi);
    }
    function cloneCheck() {
        var aydi = $('input#gizli').val();
        $table = $('table#table0').clone().attr('id', 'table' + aydi).attr(
                'name', 'table' + aydi).appendTo("#div1");
        $("input[type='radio']", $table).prop("name", "ans" + aydi);
        $("input[type='radio']", $table).prop("type", "checkbox");
        $("p", $table).prop("id", "questionTXT_" + aydi);
        aydi++;
        $('input#gizli').val(aydi);
    }

    function cloneTextField() {
        var aydi = $('input#gizli').val();
        $table = $('table#table0').clone().attr('id', 'table' + aydi).attr(
                'name', 'table' + aydi).appendTo("#div1");
        $("input[type='radio']", $table).prop("name", "ans" + aydi); // to increase name property of radiobuttons
        $("input[type='radio']", $table).prop("type", "text"); // turns radiobuttons to checkboxes
        $("p", $table).prop("id", "questionTXT_" + aydi);
        aydi++;
        $('input#gizli').val(aydi);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="gizli" name="gizli" value="1" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <!-- HIDDEN VARIABLE IS FOR INCREASING ID -->
    <div id="div0" style="display: none">
        <table border="1" id="table0" name="table0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <p id="questionTXT_1">Question text will be here</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" id="A" name="ans0" /> answer1 <br />
                </td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="B" name="ans0" /> answer2 <br />
                </td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="C" name="ans0" /> answer3 <br />
                </td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="D" name="ans0" /> answer4 <br />
                </td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="E" name="ans0" /> answer5 <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="div1">
        <!-- CLONNED TABLES WILL BE HERE -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="button1" name="clonner"
            value="Add Radiobutton" onClick="cloneRadio()" /> <input
            type="button" id="button1" name="clonner" value="Add Checkbox"
            onClick="cloneCheck()" /> <input type="button" id="button1"
            name="clonner" value="Add TextField" onClick="cloneTextField()" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While I formatted the HTML for you, I would strongly recommend you revise your posted code and pare it down to a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct/Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/) for us to help you with it. Ideally post a live, minimal, demo to reproduce your problem at a site such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) (among others); that way we can see what's going on without wading through everything else.

Comment: sorry, i think it was too long to share here. after i publish, i immediately try remove it and upload file into another location.

i didn't used js fiddle before but now i'm going to paste my code there too.

Comment: @DavidThomas , i boy.. i removed your edit too :/

Comment: There are a lot of questions that need answering before we can help you. 1) Is the hidden table just a template to build on or will it contain the question with all the added answer types? 2) Each additional radio/checkbox/text should be added to a new question or a completely different question 3) Are the radio buttons going to be grouped together (only one radio button selectable in the group)? etc... maybe giving us a bit more information about what you are trying to do would help.

Comment: 1)i use hidden table just as a template.
2)each questions will be different, i'm planning to change them by quickedit plugin of jquery
3)only one radiobutton selectable in a group. for multiple selects, i added checkboxes by jQuery